# why does operator new function need cast

Tags: c++, new-operator

So this statement allocates memory but does not call MyClass's constructur

```
  MyClass *ptr = (MyClass*)::operator new (sizeof(MyClass));
```

Why does `(MyClass*)` have to be cast, or is that not what's going on here?

Comment: You'll probably need to call a constructor afterwards.

Comment: right, but this is just for allocating the memory needed for the object

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What Matt McNabb and Brian Bi said, but also, this is For Your Own Good™. You shouldn't cast the pointer, but should keep it as `void*`. That way, you won't accidentally use it as the target type without constructing it first (by using a placement `new`). e.g.,

```
void* p = ::operator new(sizeof (MyClass));
MyClass* pmc = new (p) MyClass;
```

Answer (score 6):

According to N3936, §3.7.4.1/1:

> An allocation function shall be a class member function or a global function; a program is ill-formed if an
>   allocation function is declared in a namespace scope other than global scope or declared static in global
>   scope. The return type shall be `void*`.

This makes sense, since `::operator new` doesn't know what type it's being used to allocate; it only knows the size. So it has to return `void*` because what else could it return?

In C++ (unlike in C), there is no implicit conversion from `void*` to pointer to object. That's why `malloc` doesn't need a cast in C, but `malloc` and `operator new` need a cast in C++.

In this particular case the cast is actually a `static_cast` since the conversion from `void*` to pointer to object is the reverse of a standard conversion. Prefer `static_cast` over the C-style cast as it is more explicit.

Answer (score 5):

The function `::operator new()` has return type `void *`.

In C++ there is no implicit conversion from `void *` to other pointer types, a cast is required.  It is similar to trying to use `malloc` in C++.

In fact, a reasonable implementation for `::operator new` would just be `return malloc(sz);`